# DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone (AEDT)

Tags: php, timezone

I'm receiving the user's timezone from an API, but when sending that string to the `DateTimeZone` constructor, it fails when the value is `AEDT` and `AEST`.

I've checked my timezonedb version and updated it to the "Olson" 2016.10 version, but the issue is still there.

According to [these](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2014-August/000023.html) release notes, `AEDT` and `AEST` should be valid timezones.

Any way I can get these 2 abbreviations to work? Seeing that I'm receiving them from an external API, I can't really change it in case it's invalid, except with an ugly hack :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php → can you see the timezone anywhere in there…? If not, you'll need to replace them with something that *is* in there.

Comment: @deceze well, the thing is, even though I don't see it in there, locally (PHP 5.6.11) it works. The only difference is that on the production server I have PHP 5.5.9.

Comment: *"__Caution__ The behavior of timezones not listed here is undefined."* – guess you found the undefined behaviour, and should therefore try to avoid it by not using unsupported timezones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I solved this issue, however I do remember it being a bug in either PHP or timezonedb.

Doing `$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'));` and getting the timezone of `$date` resulted in `AEDT`, which then again was not recognized by PHP as a valid timezone.

What I ended up doing was to upgrade PHP to a slightly newer version.